# Rails + Devise, registration form with nested attributes not creating associated record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I have a simple form_for using Devise but I'm having issues with nested attributes:

**routes.rb**

```
devise_for :guest, controllers: {
  registrations: 'guests/registrations'
}
```

**devise/registrations/new.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for @guest, url: guest_registration_path do |f| %>
  <%= f.email_field :email %>
  <%= f.text_field :first_name %>
  <%= f.text_field :last_name %>
  <%= f.password_field :password %>
  <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %>
  <%= f.check_box :plus_one %>
  <%= f.fields_for :invite do |i| %>
    <%= i.text_field :first_name %>
    <%= i.text_field :last_name %>
  <% end %>
  <%= f.submit "Log In" %>
```

**guests/registrations_controller.rb**

```
class Guests::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController

  def new
    @guest = Guest.new
    @guest.invite = Invite.new
  end

  protected

    def sign_up_params
      params.require(:guest).permit!
    end

end
```

**guest.rb**

```
class Guest < ApplicationRecord

  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :recoverable, :trackable

  has_one :invite

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :invite

end
```

**invite.rb**

```
class Invite < ApplicationRecord

  belongs_to :guest

end
```

When it attempts to create the `Guest` using the nested attributes I get this error -

`ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: Invite guest must exist`

I've used forms with nested attributes in Rails before using this same setup so I'm wondering if it some Devise specific method I'm missing. It appears as though its not creating the `Invite` record with the correct `guest_id` and I can't figure out what the issue is.

Comment: It looks like if I flip `Guest` to `belongs_to` and `Invite` to `has_one` it creates both correctly. Is there a way to do it the original way I had it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you are using Rails 5, `belongs_to` requires association record must be exist by default. If so, then you need to add `inverse_of` to your associations:

```
class Guest
  has_one :invite, inverse_of: :guest
end

class Invite
  belongs_to :guest, inverse_of: :invite
end
```

Comment: That works! Thank you, I was really stumped on that one.